# Vending machine change function

Tags: c++, interview-questions, change-making-problem

Write a function that takes an amount of money `M`, a price `P` and returns the change given in the smallest number of coins. The following coins are available: 1c, 5c, 10c, 25c, 50c, and $1. Time: 20min.

I'm looking for all sorts of reviews considering the time limit and environment.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getChange(double M, double P)
{
  /*
    1c, 5c, 10c, 25c, 50c, and $1
    getChange(3.14, 1.99) should return [0,1,1,0,0,1]
    getChange(4, 3.14) should return [1,0,1,1,1,0]
    getChange(0.45, 0.34) should return [1,0,1,0,0,0]
  */

  int denominations[] = {1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100};
  std::vector<int> r(sizeof denominations / sizeof denominations[0]);

  // I had a floating-point problem here by computing cents = (M-P)*100;
  // it took me a few minutes to figure it out
  int cents = (int)(M*100) - (int)(P*100);

  for(int i = sizeof denominations / sizeof denominations[0] - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    r[i] = cents / denominations[i];
    cents = cents % denominations[i];
  }

  return r;
}

int main()
{
  auto change = getChange(5, 0.99);
  for(auto i : change){
      std::cout << i << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You still have a floating point problem

If you change your line to this input:

```
auto change = getChange(0.04, 0.03);
```

you will get the following output:

```
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

As you can see, it answers with 2 pennies instead of one.  The problem is with the line that you "fixed":

> ```
> // I had a floating-point problem here by computing cents = (M-P)*100;
> // it took me a few minutes to figure it out
> int cents = (int)(M*100) - (int)(P*100);
> ```

You did notice a problem with your floating point conversion but you came to the conclusion that it was the subtraction that was the problem.  The actual problem is that a floating point value of something like `0.03` can sometimes be slightly above or slightly below the actual value of `0.03`.  In this case, it is slightly below.  When you convert this value to cents by using `(int)(P*100)`, you end up converting something like `2.999999` to `2` instead of `3`.

One way to avoid this problem is to *round* instead of *truncate*.  So you can change your line to this to fix the problem:

```
int cents = (int) (100*(M-P) + 0.5);
```

Comment: I noticed it later, but that was the quick solution I found within the time limit to pass the test cases.

Comment: Why did you choose `0.5`?

Comment: Because when you do `(int) (floatVar + 0.5)` it rounds to the nearest integer value.  Be careful, this only works for positive values.  You could use the `round()` function if you are dealing with negative values as well.

Answer (score 2):

## State your assumptions

The problem statement didn't specify the input and output formats, so document your choices.  Personally, I would have chosen a fixed-point representation (e.g. a `long` number of cents) for input rather than floating-point, and some form of "bag" structure (e.g. `std::map<int,long>` representing value and quantity) for the output.

## Unit tests - lots of them

You've included a single "happy-path" test, but I'd like to see a lot more.

What if `P` > `M`?  Does `P` == `M` work correctly?  What if `P` and/or `M` is ±infinity, or NaN?

## The denominations don't need to be modifiable or local

The `denominations` array can be constant:

```
static const int denominations[] = {1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100};
```

Because it is superincreasing, it may simplify the code significantly to express it sorted in the reverse order, i.e. `{100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 1}`, so that we can iterate over it in the natural order.

At some point, we'd be likely to pass it as a parameter (to allow for future changes to coinage, or use in other countries - e.g. in Scotland, we'd use `{200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1}`).

---

## Improved version

```
#include <map>

using coin_bag = std::map<unsigned int, unsigned long>;

// Calculate the change from P-M as a bag of coins
// Empty result may mean M==P or an error condition such as underpayment.
// Otherwise, it's a map of coin value => number of coins
// Note: we make no attempt to avoid or detect integer overflow.
coin_bag getChange(long M, long P)
{
    if (M <= P) {
        // no change given
        return {};
    }
    auto change = M - P;

    static const auto denominations = {100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 1};
    coin_bag coins;
    for (auto c: denominations) {
        auto q = change / c;
        if (q > 0) {
            coins[c] = q;
            change -= c * q;
        }
    }

    return coins;
}


// Test program

#include <iostream>

// helper
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const coin_bag& coins)
{
    const char *sep = "";
    os << "{";
    for(auto i : coins) {
        os << sep << i.second << " x " << i.first << 'c';
        sep = ", ";
    }
    os << "}";
    return os;
}


int test_change(long money, long price, const coin_bag& expected)
{
    auto actual = getChange(money, price);
    if (actual == expected) {
        // passed
        return 0;
    }

    // failed!
    std::cout << "Failed: getChange(" << money << ", " << price << ")"
              << " == " << actual << " != " << expected << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    return test_change(0, 0, {})
        +  test_change(-1, 0, {})
        +  test_change(0, 1, {}) // underpaid
        +  test_change(0, -1, {{1, 1}}) // refund
        +  test_change(9, 0, {{5, 1}, {1, 4}})
        // and the examples from the original comments:
        +  test_change(314, 199, {{100, 1}, {10, 1}, {5, 1}})
        +  test_change(400, 314, {{50, 1}, {25, 1}, {10, 1}, {1, 1}})
        +  test_change(45, 34, {{10, 1}, {1, 1}})
        ;
}
```

---

## Enhancement: show coin names

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

using coin_bag = std::map<unsigned int, unsigned long>;

static const std::map<unsigned int, const char*, std::greater<unsigned int>>
us_coins = {{100, "$1"}, {50, "50¢"}, {25, "25¢"}, {10, "10¢"}, {5, "5¢"}, {1, "1¢"}};


// Calculate the change from P-M as a bag of coins
// Empty result may mean M==P or an error condition such as underpayment.
// Otherwise, it's a map of coin value => number of coins
// Note: we make no attempt to avoid or detect integer overflow.
coin_bag getChange(long M, long P)
{
    if (M <= P) {
        // no change given
        return {};
    }
    auto change = M - P;

    coin_bag coins;
    for (auto c: us_coins) {
        auto q = change / c.first;
        if (q > 0) {
            coins[c.first] = q;
            change -= c.first * q;
        }
    }

    return coins;
}


// Test program

#include <iostream>

// helper
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const coin_bag& coins)
{
    const char *sep = "";
    os << "{";
    for(auto i : coins) {
        os << sep << i.second << " x " << us_coins.at(i.first);
        sep = ", ";
    }
    os << "}";
    return os;
}


int test_change(long money, long price, const coin_bag& expected)
{
    auto actual = getChange(money, price);
    if (actual == expected) {
        // passed
        return 0;
    }

    // failed!
    std::cout << "Failed: getChange(" << money << ", " << price << ")"
              << " == " << actual << " != " << expected << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    return test_change(0, 0, {})
        +  test_change(-1, 0, {})
        +  test_change(0, 1, {}) // underpaid
        +  test_change(0, -1, {{1, 1}}) // refund
        +  test_change(9, 0, {{5, 1}, {1, 4}})
        // and the examples from the original comments:
        +  test_change(314, 199, {{100, 1}, {10, 1}, {5, 1}})
        +  test_change(400, 314, {{50, 1}, {25, 1}, {10, 1}, {1, 1}})
        +  test_change(45, 34, {{10, 1}, {1, 1}})
        ;
}
```

Comment: The expected input was floating-point. I know it's not the correct way of handling money, but that's the task I was given.

Comment: In that case, pay attention to test cases involving binary/decimal rounding issues and non-finite numbers; you should also think about values where the precision is no longer within `0.01`.  Since the question didn't state, I had to assume you had a free choice of interface.  The rest of the answer should still have some useful nuggets for you.

Answer (score 1):

General approach looks good. But loop in the getChange I really do not like... So I have modified your code adding comments about every change I made. To make it easier to find - I have removed your comments - it is not indication that they not belong - just temporal workaround...

```
std::vector<int> getChange(double M, double P)
{
    //use vector instead of C-array
    //add const
    //reverse order of values
    const std::vector<int>  denominations = {100,50,25,10,5,1};
    std::vector<int> r;//init empty vector - plan to use emplace_back

    //since the final size is known - 
    //set the proper capacity to avoid copying when resizing
    r.reserve(denominations.size());

    //use static_cast instead of C-style cast
    //adding rounding fix
    int cents = static_cast<int>(M*100+.5) - static_cast<int>(P*100+.5);

    for(auto val:denominations) { //get rid of horrible index loop
        //since we do not have index - use emplace_back
        r.emplace_back( cents / val); 
        cents %= val;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Now the function logic is the same - just the order of values in the result is opposite. I feel like code looks cleaner like this.

For the main - - it is just a preference - I would want to see count of coins with names. So I have extended the loop in main to add this functionality - but this modification is completely optional.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto change = getChange(3.14, 1.99);

    //create parallel vector of names
    const std::vector<std::string>  den_names = {"1$","50c","25c","10c","5c","1c"};

    //go over 2 vectors in parallel using const iterator
    auto it2 = den_names.cbegin();
    for(auto it = change.cbegin(); it != change.cend(); ++it,++it2) {
        if(*it > 0) {//skip zeros
            //show both - count of coins and coin name
            std::cout << *it << "*" << *it2 << ", "; 
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Much more idiomatic, but it has the same floating-point problems as mine. Check @JS1's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple check in your for loop for case less than 5.

```
if(cent < 5 ){ 
   returnChange[0] = cent; 
   break; 
}
```

Comment: Please argue the pros and cons of such a special case. (looks dangerous - what if there was a tuppence? Better check if smaller than smallest denomination larger than one cent.)